# Trying to implement alarm with a notification

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am getting "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" error. I even tried to put getActivity() before it but it was of no help.

code for AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.archana.pocketfriendly;

import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
MediaPlayer alarm;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
     //Acquire the lock
     wl.acquire();

     //You can do the processing here update the widget/remote views.
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

     if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
         msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
     }
     Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
     alarm = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm);
     alarm.start();
     msgStr.append("Do you want to enter the expenses?\nIgnore if already done!");
     Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     Vibrator vib=(Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
     vib.vibrate(2000);

  // notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.settings)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenu.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainMenu.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  //error in this      `enter code here`line.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

     //Release the lock
     wl.release();


}
public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //After after 30 seconds
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 86400 , pi); 
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context){
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
}
}
```

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like your other calls to `getSystemService`, you need to perform it on a context object:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```